# Extracting values with jq only when they exist

Tags: jq

I have a large file of records that contain fields that look something like this:

```
   {
  "id": "1000001",
  "updatedDate": "2018-12-21T01:52:00Z",
  "createdDate": "1993-11-30T02:59:25Z",
  "varFields": [
    {
      "fieldTag": "b",
      "content": "1000679727"
    },
    {
      "fieldTag": "v",
      "content": "v.1"
    }
```

}

I need to extract the .content element along with other things, but only when the fieldTag associated with it is "v". Only some records contain a fieldTag "v".

When I try to parse using

```
 (.varFields[] |select(.fieldTag=="v") | "\(.content)") // ""
```

it works fine so long as v is present. However, when it is not present, I get

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:353953): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

I tried to get rid of the error with multiple variations, including things to the effect of

```
(select((.varFields[] |select(.fieldTag=="v") | .content) != null) | .varFields[] |select(.fieldTag=="v") | "\(.content)") // ""
```

but I'm still getting the same error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [error suppression operator ?](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ErrorSuppression/OptionalOperator:?) that works a bit like the new ?. nullable chaining operator in Javascript.

```
The ? operator, used as EXP?, is shorthand for try EXP.

Example:
jq '[.[]|(.a)?]'
Input   [{}, true, {"a":1}]
Output  [null, 1]
```

They have a slightly simpler demonstrable example of this at https://jqplay.org/jq?q=%5B.%5B%5D%7C(.a)%3F%5D&j=%5B%7B%7D%2C%20true%2C%20%7B%22a%22%3A1%7D%5D and the [try-catch](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#try-catch) operator is similar if all you need is custom error handling (or just error ignoring...).

Comment: I found an error that requires information not in my original question but which caused the failure.

That means I think this is a bad question, but I'm leaving it up because the mention of the error suppression operator and try-catch mechanisms may be useful to others